How to automatically convert all assertions of a "classical model" into assertions of a "constraint model" in NUnit?
Is there a tool to automatically convert "classical model" assertions into "constraint model" assertions for all tests?
The Nuget package NUnit.Analyzers offers automatic refactoring, but it only works for a single assertion.
For example, Classical model:
Assert.IsTrue(sut.Value);

Constraint model:
Assert.That(sut.Value, Is.True);


regex is your friend. You can even write your own code-analyzer.

https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/constraints/Constraints.html

First thing, you might use Regex to convert all Assert. to ClassicAssert. so that the code would compile.
When I did this in my own project, I proceeded with this approach to do the whole thing. I wrote a Regex for each pattern with a capturing group in replacement. It worked fine.
But now for this question, I found a better way to automate this. I didn't realise there was an analyzer suggestion for it.
In Visual Studio, VS Code, or Rider, you can select any quick fix and apply it to the whole document, project, or solution.
But even without that, you can run the fix from the command prompt like that:
 dotnet format *.csproj --diagnostics NUnit2003 --severity info

You can use a specific csproj or sln file as needed. NUnit2003 is the code of the fix that I saw in my simple test, and you need --severity info because these are not included by default even if you name the diagnostic you are fixing.

Very nice!
I use nuget package NUnit.Analyzers and use analyzer NUnit2005
Thank You!

P.S.
NUnit2001 NUnit2002 NUnit2003 NUnit2004 NUnit2005 NUnit2015 NUnit2017
NUnit2019 NUnit2035 NUnit2048 NUnit2049

Oh. Sorry about that!

Certain things don't have a fix, like NUnit2007. Here, a Regx would work better.

Or, if you don't mind applying the fixes for any other info severity (non NUnit), this command will also work: dotnet format *.csproj --severity info (remove the diagnostics parameter).
